# Can't running my ubuntu 20.04 after installed rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, ubuntu-20.04

I installed rabbitMQ on my ubuntu 20.04, but when i restart my computer it can't start correctly.

My error message is :

> Failed to start RabbitMQ Messaging server.

Do you have any idea what can i do?

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't run your Ubuntu. It just means that RabbitMQ didn't start. Your title doesn't match your post.

Comment: without any logs or error, it is hard to understand. check the systems logs